# Do Prolog coroutines have a notion of solution and therefore determinism?

Tags: prolog, delayed-execution, nlp-question-answering

[@false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) posed an interesting challenge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66132873/502187) in the comment section concerning determinism. He not only questions whether there is a difference between solution and answer. A distinction which might affect the notion of determinism. But also whether this query here:

```
?- freeze(_,false).
```

Has a solution? Since delayed execution is not in the scope of the original question, this new question should offer a platform to settle the terminological problem, also in hindsight of what is determinism.

Comment: This goal has an answer but no solution.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse: surely you can add that predicate to your Strawberry Prolog yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refutation that the goal has no solution, contrary to what @false claims. If it had no solution, then `(\+)/1` would turn it into a yes. But it doesn't, it turns it into a no:

```
?- \+ freeze(_,false).
false.
```

Its probably rather programming error, to have a delayed goal that
isn't satisfiable. Delayed goal should express a "MAYBE". If the "MAYBE" is
always a "NO", then a delayed goal doesn't make any sense.

The effect of `(\+)/1` is then that it turns "MAYBE" and "YES" into "NO",
and "NO" into "YES". A residual problem is though, that there could be multiple delayed goals that are not satisfiable as a conjunction.